# ¿porque los sockets solo funcionan en mi wifi?

Tags: c, socket

El problema que tengo es que el programa de sockets que tengo hecho solo funciona entre dos programas que están en mi ordenador o dos preogramas que están en ordenadores conectados al mismo router creo que el problema es que tengo que abrir un puerto en mi router y que el programa use ese puerto pero no estoy seguro de si es así.

además al abrir el puerto he introducido la IP de mi ordenador donde tengo el programa que hace de servidor pero me pone puerto de entrada y puerto de salida con unos números y no se que hacer con ellos.

Comment: El puerto de entrada es donde "escucha" el ruteador, el puerto de salida es donde "escucha" tu servidor.

Comment: Si quieres que funcione fuera de tu red local tienes que conseguir una ip estatica, y algo con los puertos que ya hoy no recuerdo. Puede que quieras hecharle un vistaso a un servicio como noip

Comment: @Sal en los dos me has puesto que escucha XD y no se si el de salida es el externo o el interno

Comment: ¿No suena raro "Salida al interior"? Suena bien "Salida al exterior".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Redes privadas y NAT

Tu wifi forma parte de lo que se llama una "red privada". Dentro de las redes privadas todas las máquinas conectadas a la misma tienen IPs que comienzan típicamente por `192.168.x.x` o bien `10.x.x.x` según cómo esté configurada.

El caso es que esas IPs se denominan "privadas" por una buena razón, y es que el router que conecta a esa subred con internet realiza una "traducción de IPs" (técnicamente se denomina NAT) de modo que todos los paquetes que salen a internet llevan otra IP, la del router, siendo imposible determinar desde afuera qué máquina interna de la subred originó la petición.

Por ejemplo, imagina que en tu wifi tienes conectados dos equipos. Uno de ellos tiene la IP 192.168.1.12 y el otro 192.168.1.19. Cada uno de esos equipos puede comunicarse directamente con el otro, pues están en la misma subred y el router no interviene en ese caso. Pero tan pronto como uno cualquiera de los dos intente conectarse por ejemplo con Google, necesitarán salir a Internet, y eso deberán hacerlo a través de router.

Supongamos que es 192.168.1.12 quien quiere conectar con google. Para ello, tras haber averiguado que la IP de google es 142.250.184.4, emite un paquete de datos TCP que lleva entre otras cosas la siguiente información:

```
IP DESTINO: 142.250.184.4 (la de la máquina destino, google)
PUERTO DESTINO: 443 (el puerto estándar para una conexión HTTPS)
IP ORIGEN: 192.168.1.12 (la de la máquina que origina la petición)
PUERTO ORIGEN: 53277 (es un puerto al azar que el PC origen ha elegido para esta comunicación)
```

Este paquete se envía al router para que lo redirija a otro router, etc, hasta que el paquete acabe llegando finalmente a Google y la conexión pueda ser establecida.

Pero ya que la IP origen es del tipo "privado", tu router estará haciendo NAT, que significa que no se limita a copiar ese paquete sin más a internet, sino que lo modifica, cambiando la **IP ORIGEN** (y posiblemente el puerto origen). En lugar de la IP origen pondrá la IP pública del propio router (el router, por estar conectado a dos redes para hacer de puente entre ambas, tiene dos IPs, una interna que será del tipo 192.168.1.xxx, que es accesible desde dentro de casa, y otra "externa" que es la que es accesible desde internet).

Supongamos que la IP pública del router es 84.3.12.4. Y que el router elige un puerto al azar, digamos el 55555. Entonces el paquete que el router enviará a internet habrá cambiado y será:

```
IP DESTINO: 142.250.184.4 (sigue siendo la de la máquina destino, google)
PUERTO DESTINO: 443 (sigue siendo el puerto estándar para una conexión HTTPS)
IP ORIGEN: 84.3.12.4 (la ip pública del router)
PUERTO ORIGEN: 55555 (el puerto elegido al azar por el router)
```

Así que cuando google reciba la petición, "verá" que su origen es 84.3.12.4, puerto 55555 y no tiene forma de saber que el verdadero origen era 192.168.1.12:53277. De hecho todas las peticiones que salen de tu casa hacia internet, no importa desde qué dispositivo sea, saldrán con "IP ORIGEN: 84.3.12.4".

Cuando Google responda, lo hará a 84.3.12.4:55555, por lo que llegará de nuevo a tu router. Tu router habrá almacenado en una memoria interna que todo lo que le llegue por el puerto 55555 era para la máquina 192.168.1.12:53227, por lo que reenviará esa respuesta a la máquina adecuada.

Eso es lo que permite que todos los ordenadores de tu casa puedan conectarse "a internet" sin problemas y no notes nada raro. Y la razón de inventar todo ese tinglado es porque el número de direcciones IPv4 está limitado y se ha agotado ya. Gracias al truco del NAT hay muchas IP repetidas (en mi casa puede haber otro ordenador cuya IP sea también 192.168.1.12, y no puede confundirse con el tuyo porque esas IPs nunca "salen" de mi casa).

### Problema

Todo eso del NAT no causa problemas mientras las conexiones se originen en tu casa y estén dirigidas a IPs públicas de internet.

Pero causa problemas obvios si en tu casa tienes un servidor y necesitas que sea accesible desde fuera, ya que ¿a dónde se tiene que conectar una máquina externa?

Supongamos que en tu máquina 192.168.1.12 has puesto un servidor escuchando en el puerto 8000. ¿Cómo podría yo desde mi casa conectar con tu servidor? El problema aqui es que si intento hacerlo a 192.168.1.12:8000, o bien me estaré conectando a algún equipo propio en mi casa, o bien obtendré un error (si no tengo equipo con esa IP). En ningún caso esa petición se entenderá como un intento de acceder a tu casa, porque esa IP es privada.

Tú podrías averiguar cuál es la IP pública de tu router. Eso es muy sencillo. Hay muchas páginas que te lo dicen. Incluso google te lo dice si le preguntas "What is my ip". En realidad google sólo tiene que imprimir cuál es la IP desde la que le llega la pregunta, ya que esa IP será la pública de tu router que ha hecho NAT.

Digamos que averiguas la IP pública de tu router y que es 84.3.12.4 y que me la dices a mi. ¿Podría yo intentar entonces conectar con 84.3.12.4:8000 para acceder a tu servidor?

Estamos más cerca de la solución, pero todavía no, porque eso me conectaría con el puerto 8000 de tu router, y no con el puerto 8000 de la máquina interna. Sólo quedaría configurar el router para decirle "toda conexión que recibas a través del puerto 8000 reenvíala al puerto 8000 de la máquina 192.168.1.12"

### Solución

Eso es lo que se conoce como *reenvío de puertos*, o PNAT. Cualquier router tiene posibilidad de hacer esto (otra cosa es encontrar cómo lo hace tu router en particular, suele estar en un apartado titulado "reenvío de puertos" o a veces "juegos y aplicaciones").

Cuando configures eso, necesitarás la siguiente información:

- IP interna. Es la ip privada de la máquina en que se ejecuta tu servidor (192.168.1.12 en el ejemplo)
- Puerto interno. Es el puerto en que escucha tu servidor (8000 en el ejemplo)
- Puerto externo. Es el puerto que el router expondrá a internet, y al que yo desde mi casa me podría conectar. Puedes elegir el que quieras, y podría ser también el 8000 si no está ya ocupado, o cualquier otro.

Una vez configurado todo eso me dirías a mi cuál es la IP pública de tu router, y el puerto externo que hayas configurado. Yo me conectaría a esa IP:puerto, y tu router redirigirá la petición a tu máquina interna. Todo funcionará ya, al menos mientras no reinicies el router pues eso puede cambiar su IP externa, o la máquina donde se ejecuta el servidor, pues eso puede cambiar su IP interna (podrías configurar el router también para evitar eso, y hacer que siempre le asigne la misma IP a ese ordenador, en base a su MAC por ejemplo).